# Limit Laravel 5 Encryption length

Tags: php, encryption, laravel-5

I have a Laravel5 web application of Business directory.

When I Encrypting a value like

```
$cryptval = Crypt::encrypt(1);

result  =  eyJpdiI6IndhaFZFNlhIRDlURzdXanJVMEhBM0E9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoidWF3VzRFZDhyRHltUlwveDdyV0VVWnc9PSIsIm1hYyI6IjE5YjA2YWIyN2Q0MTBlYjdhNDJiNDE5ZjY2OGQ2MDA2NzQ3ZTA4ODc4NzY0ZTIwMjBiMzQxN2RjNmM5ZDg3ZjYifQ==
```

its  giving a long string about 250 length.

Is there any way to limit the length of this string in laravel?

My Client needs to add the URL with encrypted value in a mail function.
     eg:

> www.example.com/varify/eyJpdiI6IndhaFZFNlhIRDlURzdXanJVMEhBM0E9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoidWF3VzRFZDhyRHltUlwveDdyV0VVWnc9PSIsIm1hYyI6IjE5YjA2YWIyN2Q0MTBlYjdhNDJiNDE5ZjY2OGQ2MDA2NzQ3ZTA4ODc4NzY0ZTIwMjBiMzQxN2RjNmM5ZDg3ZjYifQ==

But the mail function only allow some length of URL :(

Comment: The ```encrypt``` method only accepts a ```$value``` parameter, so there's no way the explicitly control the length of the hash. Why do you need it to be shorter?

Comment: what for do you need crypting ?

Comment: Is encryption really what you need here? Perhaps you should be using some kind of token system instead? (hint: encrypted strings are not something you normally put into a URL)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hiding true database object ID in url's](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32795998/hiding-true-database-object-id-in-urls)

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to store the hashed values in a table, and then reference the hash by the auto-incrementing ID of the hash value.

```
| id | hash             | timestamp | random_key |
| 1  | some-hash        | 125346164 | 21415      |
| 2  | some-other-hash  | 123513515 | 25151      |
```

So now, instead of using:

```
www.example.com/verify/some-hash
```

You can use:

```
www.example.com/verify/1
```

The `id` should really be obfuscated, and not used just as an integer - which is where the timestamp and random_key can help.

```
$id = 1;
$timestamp = 125346164;
$randomKey = 21415;

$key = base64_encode($timestamp . $randomKey . $id);

echo 'http://www.domain.com/verify/' . $key;

// http://www.domain.com/verify/MTI1MzQ2MTY0MjE0MTUx
```

All that being said, my recommendation would be to try to work around the limitation put in place by the e-mail delivery platform as [URL's can support an address length of around 2000 characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/417142/what-is-the-maximum-length-of-a-url-in-different-browsers). The example you gave only had a length of 32 and falls well within the lengths acceptable by any modern browser.

**Edit**: Just generate a uuid using a package like [this](https://github.com/webpatser/laravel-uuid) rather than trying to create your own random id. This will produce a string such as `d3d29d70-1d25-11e3-8591-034165a3a613`.

Comment: This would make it extremely easy for someone to guess thus making the hash redundant.

Comment: Agreed it's not perfect in the example's format. It needs obfuscating further to be useful which could be done by appending a timestamp to the ```id```. Will update the example.

Comment: Base64-encoding a number as obfuscation would be to a programmer like ... I don't know. Write cleartext? Everyone knows about base64-encoding, the resulting character set and the == gives it away big-time.

Comment: The question I'm answering isn't really about obfuscating, it's about shortening a string. My answer achieves that. We've no context as to the importance of the hash (the OP's original example is simply hashing a value of ```1```). Laravel's encrypt is also doing a base64_encode on the encrypted value. I simply added some obfuscation as Ian's point of guessing the ```id``` is perfectly valid.

Comment: Totally agree with you @Amo, it does seem like the OP may be a little out of his/her depth with all being considered... OP, Google it :)

Comment: Don't use a hash (they're brute forceable), don't encrypt. Use a separate unique value. https://paragonie.com/blog/2015/09/comprehensive-guide-url-parameter-encryption-in-php

Comment: Again, the question was about shortening a string, not about security. Perhaps my answer should reflect something simpler (albeit not much shorter) such as a UUID.

Comment: "the question was about shortening a string, not about security". Yes, and the only way to shorten the ciphertext is to remove the security to the point that you might as well not encrypt in the first place. If you want a short, unique, pseudorandom identifier, just add a column to your table.

Answer (score 1):

I just faced the same problem. I simply added a column 'hash' in my database table. Then I filled it with a md5(encrypt($model->id))

The md5 value is much shorter, and because it also uses Laravel's crypt, it can't be guessed.

Comment: This doesn't make any sense, yeah it's shorter but you can't decrypt it you're just hashing it and there are functions for hashing you don't need to encrypt it then hash it, this is just plain redundant if not wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I think dont need to store nothing in database, that is a hard work,
In my case a use base64_encode in blase and use base64_decode in controller to show the real value to method and continue the process.